# apache 2 failing to start on Ubuntu 10

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-10.04

I'm an Ubuntu machine with Apache 2 virtual hosts.

I can't diagnose this problem because my error log doesn't seem to reflect the problem

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
* Starting web server apache2                            [fail] 

$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status
Apache is NOT running.
```

This seems to have started after I edited a virtual host, but I'm fairly certain I fixed that file and now Apache doesn't want to start anymore.

Comment: Could you please post your configuration file..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ sudo service apache2 start
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  I solved it.  One of my apache virtual hosts was looking for an error file in a directory that I had renamed.